# List and selected Preview PDFs Side by Side HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to build this webpage where LEFT side is list of PDFs and the RIGHT side is preview panel. But I'm not able to get it done. I've used **frameset** to split this webpage. Left col with List and Right is preview.

Ideal : Whenever user clicks on pdf LEFT side It should preview or open PDF in RIGHT side of frame.

Please help me with this project. It'll be really helpful for me.

**Thank you so much in advance**.

[Please see webpage preview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXVMB.jpg)

Comment: Hi @KARAN - I would recommend, that you think about another solution first. **Frameset is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset)**

Maybe start with displaying a preview alone and ask questions if you get stuck. Afterward, think about a solution on how to build your HTML page and display a selected pdf.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Thank you Uwe and Zoli for the response Uwe, I work on your suggestions and get back with the code Zoli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, maybe. It sounds simple enough:

See the [JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/NoobishPro/3sfnvzpL/7/)

Unfortunately, JSFiddle blocks the actual loading of said PDF, but it should work when you copy-paste the code.

You haven't given any limitations or information about your requirements or limitations, so I'm following your tags and using javascript to make it work.

The code;

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column_left">
        <!-- your list of items. Example; -->
        <ul>
            <li class="pdf_link" data-pdf="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf">Example PDF</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column_right">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
  html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    }

  .wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

  .column_left {
    width: calc(30% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    }

  .column_right {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    }

  ul {
    height: 100%;
    }

  li.pdf_link {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

  li.pdf_link:hover {
    color: blue;
    }
```

### Javascript

```
let el_listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.pdf_link');
let el_pdfContainer = document.querySelector('.column_right');

el_listItems.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', openPDF);
});

function openPDF(e)
{
    let pdfLink = this.getAttribute('data-pdf');
    el_pdfContainer.innerHTML = `<object data="${pdfLink}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <p>Your browser doesn't seem to support PDF files.</p>
                                    <a href="${pdfLink}">Or click here to download the PDF</a>
                                </object>`;
}
```